# How to Prefilter dates before grouping

Tags: mysql, group-by

I've grouped some MySQL data to perform some concatenation of fields. However I have dates which I need to find the earliest date before grouping, then display the earliest startdate and latest finishdate in the result.

```
SELECT *,
GROUP_CONCAT(RTRIM(inventoryID),' x ',qty SEPARATOR' + ') AS jobs
FROM Jobs WHERE ordernbr = '150002' GROUP BY grouping
```

My Table data is in the format of:

`OrderNbr, Qty, InventoryID, StartDate, FinishDate, RequestedDate, OrderDate`

After grouping, I need the result to show:

`InventoryID, Qty, EarliestStartDate, LatestFinishDate, OrderDate, RequestedDate, jobs`

But I'm not sure how to find and display dates before and after grouping.

I'm thinking something like this

```
SELECT MIN(startdate) AS EarlistStartDate,
GROUP_CONCAT(RTRIM(inventoryID),' x ',qty SEPARATOR' + ') AS jobs
FROM Jobs WHERE ordernbr = '150002' GROUP BY grouping
```

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO and desired output for this data. Also specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: I have been assigned the task of reviewing this question, as it was authored by a new contributor. Question looks to be in order. +1Up+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the earliest start date and latest finish date inside the grouping, then this should suffice:

```
SELECT MIN(startdate) AS EarliestStartDate, MAX(finishDate) AS LatestFinishDate
GROUP_CONCAT(RTRIM(inventoryID),' x ',qty SEPARATOR' + ') AS jobs
FROM Jobs WHERE ordernbr = '150002' GROUP BY grouping
```

However, if you need to find the latest finish date before the grouping and the earliest start date after the grouping, then you would need to do something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(latestbefore.finishDate, jbgroup.EarliestStartDate),
       COALESCE(earliestafter.startDate, jbgroup.LatestFinishDate),
       jbgroup.jobs
FROM
(
SELECT MIN(startdate) AS EarliestStartDate,
GROUP_CONCAT(RTRIM(inventoryID),' x ',qty SEPARATOR' + ') AS jobs
FROM Jobs WHERE ordernbr = '150002' GROUP BY grouping
) jbgroup
LEFT JOIN jobs latestbefore
ON latestbefore.finishDate <= jbgroup.EarliestStartDate
LEFT JOIN jobs afterlatestbefore
ON afterlatestbefore.finishDate > latestbefore.finishDate AND
   afterlatestbefore.finishdate <= jbgroup.EarliestStartDate
LEFT JOIN jobs earliestafter
ON earliestafter.startDate >= jbgroup.LatestFinishDate
LEFT JOIN jobs beforeearliestafter
ON beforeearliestafter.startDate < earliestafter.startDate AND
   beforeearliestafter.startDate >= jbgroup.LatestFinishDate
WHERE afterlatestbefore.finishDate IS NULL AND
      beforeearliestafter.finishDate IS NULL;
```

Explanation:

- we use our initial query as a subselect, getting the groups
- `latestbefore` is the latest date before the group
- we guarantee that `latestbefore` is the latest date before the group via ensuring that no such `afterlatestbefore` exists that is before the group but after `latestbefore`
- `earliestafter` is the earliest date after the group
- we guarantee that `earliestafter` is the earliest date after the group via ensuring that no such `beforeearliestafter` exists that is after the group but before `earliestafter`